# python pandas use previous calculated values

Tags: python, pandas, calculated-columns, shift

I'm new in python and i have a issue i can't fix. So, i need your help.
I have a dataframe df with two columns: Close_M and Close_AA.
The point is, i would like calculate two new columns Resultat_M and Resultat_AA like this:

```
for i in symbol_list:
    df['Result'+'_'+i] = (df['Close'+'_'+i] / df ['Close'+'_'+i].shift(1) ) * df['Result'+'_'+i].shift(1)`
```

I want to initialise the value of Resultat column with value of 100.

**Input dataframe**:

```
 Close_M 

  10         
   5         
  12         
  14      

Close_AA

8         
9         
10      
7
```

**Output dataframe expected**:

```
Resultat_M

 100       
 50        
 120         
 140

Resultat_AA  

 100         
 112,5       
 125         
 87,5
```

For example Resultat_M, 50=(5/10)*100 ;
                     120 = (12/5)*50;

[image: python error viewed]

But my code does not work. Have you an idea about how to do that?
Thanks

After correction, i have the same error:

[image: See a screenshot of what i'm running in python]

The output when i run the code you give me in your answer:

**Output dataframe i have:**

```
Resultat_AA

Nan

112,5

111,11

70

Resultat_M

Nan

50

240

116,6666667
```

why i don't have the expected result? I think after division, it multiplies each row by 100, not by the previous value calculated as i would like.

Answer (score 0):

1. pre-set the result column with the initial values:

   ```
   df ['Result_' + i] = 100
   ```
2. Compute the actual values in the result columns

   ```
   df['Result'+'_'+i] = (df['Close'+'_'+i].iloc[1:] / df ['Close'+'_'+i].iloc[:-1] ) * df['Result'+'_'+i].iloc[:-1]
   ```

Please note that the first term is being iterated to pre-last value.

Comment: Thank you for the response. How can i initialize the first value of column Result to 100 , before start calculation?

Comment: `df['Result'].iloc[0] = 100`

Comment: I get an error. Please see python error link add to my question above.

Comment: The error tells you that there is no `Result_M` column in your dataframe. So, there should be something wrong when you set the columns names. Could you provide more code and indicate the line where it fails? UPD: BTW, the names of the columns in your example and in the code  differ - `Resultat` and `Result` - is not it the reason?

Comment: After correction i have the same error, i add a screeshot of what i running in python

Comment: Aah, I beg your pardon - I misunderstood what you meant. You **do not** have the Result columns prior to the computations. (Actually, you already fall into the error when trying to run `df['Result_M'].iloc[0] = 100` So, you need first to initialize the columns. Instead of the former, do `df['Result_' + i] = 100` (without `iloc`). This will set the new column and fill it with 100. Then should be all right. I've edited the answer.

Comment: After running your code, idon't have the expected output. Please see the output in question edit above.